# How to fix my code to reset rows when none are found

Tags: php, mysqli

I grab random rows, 100 at a time and once used I mark the column 'used' with a 1. I need to reset all those with a 1 when it has no more that are marked 0 to pick from. Here is my code for this...

```
 $result = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT id, unit_id, shown FROM units WHERE suspended = '0' AND used = '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100"); 
 while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if (!$result){
   $result2 = mysqli_query($res, "UPDATE units SET used='0' WHERE used = 
 '1'");
}
else{
 other code here
}
 }
 $res->close();
```

I have also tried this:

```
 if ($myrow[id] == ''){
```

But that does not work either. I just need to know when it has marked all of them used so it can reset 'used' back to 0 so it will start over again.

I have also tried moving the if statement outside the while and it still is not working.

It should be noted that this runs on a cron.

Comment: Move the `if(!$result)` outside of the while loop. Also, `mysqli_query` returns a [mysqli_result](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object with SELECT statements, so you need to either use a counter inside the loop and check for an empty counter after the loop, or check for [num_rows](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) (be sure to read the note on that page)

Comment: _"I grab random tables"_ - You mean random _rows_ in a table, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$i = 0;` outside the while and inside it add 1. After the while loop check if the **$i** is less than 100 and if it is then for sure you reached the end of the list, but if **$i** is equal 100 then you need to check with dB query, because there is a chance that you have result with the last 100 records and again it will be the end of the list.

Comment: I did not even think about doing it this way, but it does work lol. So I am doing it this way now. Thanks for the answer.